# What is the best approach for setting Wintesmith up with multiple sites?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, wintersmith

I am about to set up Wintersmith (wintersmith.io) for two separate sites (one content site and one app) and was wondering if there are any 'gotchas' or best practices with regards to this.

The plan is to use Wintersmith, Jade, LESS, Html5Boilerplate and Bootstrap for some rapid prototyping and fast iterations to test some concepts.

Any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you mean by setting up multiple sites. If you need to serve several sites under the same domain you can use the `baseUrl` config option. Other than that it's just `wintersmith new`, a tip is to set up your own templates in `~/.wintersmith/templates` so you can easily set up a new site using your preferred configuration and plugins. `wintersmith new --template yourtemplate`

Also check out the browserify plugin, it's great for apps.

Comment: Thanks Johan, spot on. I meant serving multiple sites, but not under the same domain.